# multi-backends haproxy best practices

Tags: haproxy

I am looking for good practices for using load balancer haproxy.

There are few DNS records to the same haproxy server, haproxy has few backends with bunch of servers.

The question is what the best practice to manage few backend clusters:

- 1st approach. On DNS server transfer all request to haproxy server IP port 80, and then on single common `frontend` routing traffic by using `cal`. This approach might became very complicated with even few backends, because for every backend we need to set acl.
- 2st approach. On every single DNS record set the same haproxy server IP and different port for specific backend, then on haproxy set fronted for every IP:port interface. This approach seems like more simpler approach, but if there are any drawbacks.

What is the preferable solution for managing many backends on haproxy?

Comment: There are *a* few DNS records ... ? What type of records? SRV? AAAA? see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types    Second problem/personal peeve: You use the pronoun *it*, bad idea in "IP port 80 and then it"

Comment: there are A records

Comment: IP Port 80 is an application layer service aka Layer 7 in 7 layer network model. DNS is layer 3. Keeping these layers separate is *VERY* important. see this image:http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.lensenet.com/OSI_Model/7layers.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.lensenet.com/OSI_Model/OSI_7-Layer_Model.html&h=494&w=646&sz=16&tbnid=JU5TzTL9OhJ_bM:&tbnh=84&tbnw=110&zoom=1&usg=__tEGMEBx6JhhfTAdvN87z4VSOMW4=&docid=ra8JR5fe5bvXjM&sa=X&ei=xu7ZULTtOY3LtAbUk4H4BQ&ved=0CE0Q9QEwBA&dur=446

Comment: @ArrowInTree, Thank you very much for the comment, what does it mean in context of my problem, should I separate it by assigned port and make dedicated frontend for each backend?

Comment: What I am trying to say is _http_ is *dependent* on _dns_, unless you give an explicit address: eg  <code>"http://127.0.0.1/ "</code>. DNS is typically configured with a primary *and* a secondary server (google's eg 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). This should not require a failover on your part. *What* you do seem to need is forwarding or tunneling. Tunneling can be done with ssh.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy is about the application layer, #7 in the 7 layer OSI model. DNS is below this level. DNS has its own scale up model: secondary servers. Google's DNS has a primary at 8.8.8.8 and a secondary at 8.8.4.4 . These addresses are very well know on the internet, so they do not need resolving. DNS for the record operates at level 4, *Transport* see this diagram: [here](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.lensenet.com/OSI_Model/7layers.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.lensenet.com/OSI_Model/OSI_7-Layer_Model.html&h=494&w=646&sz=16&tbnid=JU5TzTL9OhJ_bM:&tbnh=84&tbnw=110&zoom=1&usg=__tEGMEBx6JhhfTAdvN87z4VSOMW4=&docid=ra8JR5fe5bvXjM&sa=X&ei=xu7ZULTtOY3LtAbUk4H4BQ&ved=0CE0Q9QEwBA&dur=446)

But HAProxy's documentation does mention bind, a DNS Server implementation, [here](http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html).